# TFS Eclipse Pending Changes not showing edited files

Tags: eclipse, azure-devops

We recently migrated to Azure devops from TFS 2015. I changed my existing TFS connection to new TFS connection url, since then my local changes are not being visible under Pending Changes. I do see the changes when I compare but I am not sure why its not showing under Pending changes. I am using Local workspace , also tried detect local changes option, synchronize option etc. Get operation works fine as well. On side note, I do see large number of files under Detected changes under Excluded changes category. Can someone advise?

Comment: Did you update your workspace to point to Azure DevOps instead of to your on-prem TFS instance?

Comment: I did change the connection to new DevOps and included the Project from the new location. What I dont understand is there are lot of candidate changes with add option when I did not even change those files.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the **Detected changes** under **Excluded changes** to check if the changed files which are supposed to be in the Pending changes are all in the **Detected changes**. And check if the **Change** type is **add**.See below. If so, the files probably are treated as new added files when you changed to the new TFS connection url.

[image]

Then you need to select the files and click the **Promote** button to promote these files to the **Included Changes** category

[image]

Comment: Thank you..I see most of my workspace files including my edited files in Detected changes under Excluded changes with Change Type Add.I already got the latest version and that file which I am editing is already in the TFS. Why is it showing as new file? If I promote it then it will  be like adding a new file which is already existing in TFS. I am lost here. Should I force the latest version using get specific version to see if that works

Comment: @Rradhak How about re-mapping to a clean local workspace?